# Prove that there is unique $p_n\in\mathbb{P}_n([a,b])$ such that $\int_{a}^bx^ip_n(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^bx^if(x)\,dx,\;\;\;0\leq i\leq n.$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given a function $f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b]),$ prove that there is unique $p_n\in\mathbb{P}_n([a,b])$ such that $$\int_{a}^bx^ip_n(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^bx^if(x)\,dx,\;\;\;0\leq i\leq n.$$

My try: Let a basis $\pi_{j}(x)=x^j,\;0\leq j\leq n$ of $\mathbb{P}_n([a,b]).$ Then the problem is linear system that uniqueness resulting from the uniqueness of the linear system.

Comment: essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745967/prove-f-p-is-orthogonal-to-all-p-in-p-na-b